# What is the difference between contract, deed and covenant?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

What is the difference between a contract, deed and a covenant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contract is an agreement legally enforceable against at least two people, in writing or otherwise.

A deed is a formal document conveying an interest in real property from one party to another.

A covenant is most typically going to refer to a condition that is part of either of those transactions, such as a contractual covenant not to compete or a deed covenant to use property in a certain way.

Comment: Thank you. Is “consideration” mandatory for a contract?

Comment: Consideration is necessary for a contract, though some agreements may be enforced as though they were contracts despite the absence of a consideration.

Comment: Thank you. Does consideration need to be monetary?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @bdb484 A deed can also give effect to an agreement (like a contract) in the absence of consideration by one party.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search for these words in the [Black's Law Dictionary](http://heimatundrecht.de/sites/default/files/dokumente/Black%27sLaw4th.pdf). That legal dictionary is a very useful starting point for when one needs to do legal research.

After reading the definitions, feel free to ask about any specific details that might remain unclear to you.